# Socket is not getting binded

Tags: php, sockets, wamp

`I am trying to learn socket programming in php step by step. But I am unable to under stand why am i seeing this error:

- ```
   Warning: socket_bind(): unable to bind address [10048]: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. in D:\wamp\www\pl\mo.php on line 16
  ```
- I have tried to change port number several times but no use. I keep seeing the same error.

  ```
  set_time_limit(0);

  $ip = "127.0.0.1";
  $port = 123;

   // set the protocols
       if( !$socket = socket_create(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0) ){
    echo "cant creat socket"    ;
  }

  echo "The socket's protocol info was set \n";

  // bind the socket
  if( !socket_bind($socket,$ip,$port) ){
  echo "can't bind socket";
  }
  ?>
  ```

Comment: <?php

    
    set_time_limit(0);

    $ip = "127.0.0.1";
    $port = 123;

    // set the protocols
    if( !$socket = socket_create(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0) ){
        echo "cant creat socket"    ;
    }

    echo "The socket's protocol info was set \n";

    // bind the socket
    if( !socket_bind($socket,$ip,$port) ){
        echo "can't bind socket";
    }
?>

Comment: Have you tried a port above 1024 ?

Comment: Yes I have tried 1234 @Johnny

Comment: Then you have a problem with your system, your code executes without warnings with port 1234 on my system

Comment: what can be that problem? any idea?